# gitlab runner using wrong docker image for build container

Tags: docker, containers, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I set up an gitlab-ci-multi-runner on my VM.
In the build process I provide an docker container with all the dependencies.
But when I run it, the runner uses a different (wrong) docker image for his build container.
The messages look like that:

> Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.2.1 (f0xxxx4)
>   on runnerVM
>   (f5xxxxf0)
>  Using Docker executor with image
>   docker.com/xxx/xxx/docker-build:stable ...
>  Using docker image
>   **sha256:fe32xxx...xxxa63c** for predefined container...
>  Pulling
>   docker image docker.com/xxx/xxx/docker-build:stable ...
>  Using
>   docker image docker.com/xxx/xxx/docker-build:stable
>   ID=**sha256:9608xxx...xxxdf09** for build container...

Can someone tell me why the runner uses a different docker image for build container?
Why is it not taking the predefined container (because that's the right one...)

Here you can see my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker.com/xxx/xxx/docker-build:stable

before_script:
  - echo "Before script"


after_script:
  - echo "After Script"

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build_release:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sudo make all BUILD_TYPE=Release
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - tag1

build_debug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sudo make all BUILD_TYPE=Debug
  only:
    - develop
    - runner-test
  tags:
    - tag1
    - tag2
```

Comment: Post your gitlab ci yaml

Answer (score 0):

In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` you are referencing the complete URL to your container; it should however be in the format `group/container`, e.g. `library/nginx`.

Optionally, you may use a specific version, e.g. `library/nginx:1.13.9`.

For more information, see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the *docker* executor. Therefore the gitlab-ci-runner is creating a new Image `gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper` which will isolate the build-steps from your VM's docker-environment. This image shall be the *predefined container*.

The stages themself will be performed inside containers of images you specify for the job or the image you specify globally for all jobs. This container is the *build container*.

The build container should be made from the image you specify with `image` on top of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. You can verify it by doing

```
$ docker image ls | grep -E '(fe32|9608)'
```

on your VM. It shows you the image names and tags of your predefined- and build-container.

Comment: Does that mean that the build container needs to have docker installed so it can pull the docker image?

Comment: @Damian No. The predefined container is created from an image with docker-capabilities and it performes your job-steps using the build-image